# how to show placeholder value after setting the value of input field as empty ""?

Tags: jquery, placeholder, input-field

I have input field with id = datepicker

```
 validationfails = true;

 if(validationfails)
 {
     $('#datepicker').val('');
     $('#datepicker').attr('placeholder','mm/dd/yyyy');
 }
```

I want to show the placeholder, if validation fails.

But the placeholder does not appear. 
When i press the backspace in the input field, it appears.

how to fix this.?

Comment: It works fine for me.. on emptying the input with `.val('')` it shows the placeholder again (without your extra code) http://jsfiddle.net/rzxsz6k8/

Comment: What browser is this in as it seems to work in chrome, ff and ie11: http://jsfiddle.net/noLwohg4/

Comment: Its chrome browser I am running the script in.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('#datepicker').attr('placeholder','mm/dd/yyyy').focus().blur();
```

Comment: This bug was just affecting us (only in Safari), the focus/blur trick fixed it for us.